# What does BASE_EXPORT in chromium sourcecode do?

Tags: c++, chromium

While studying the [chromium source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master) I found that many classes are using a macro `BASE_EXPORT` defined in [base_export.h](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/base/base_export.h) which is supposed to decorate classes and functions for public use.

I just can't wrap my head around this concept? Is this supposed to substitute the "classical" approach of having an include folder for example where all headers are placed which are meant for public use?
How does `BASE_EXPORT` work exactly? How is one supposed to use such a decorated function when adding a new feature to chromium for example?

Many thanks in advance for helpful answers.

Comment: `__declspec(dllexport)`, `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` etc are implementation specific extensions provided by compilers so that the types you decorate them with can be accessed across DLL/shared object boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the functionality needed for multiple implementations (operating systems) to export functions from shared/dynamic libraries

Answer (score 2):

Chromium support building chrome using a component build(multiple shared libraries) and regular build (single library).

In component builds, the component being built, e.g., BASE, NET, CONTENT, use a `<COMPONENT>_EXPORT` macro name ex: BASE_EXPORT for BASE component.

When this macro is used for building the component, the macro expands as `__declspec(dllexport)` on MSVC compiler and `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` on GCC/Clang. This helps the component to export stuff to be used from outside (external visibility).

When it symbols is used by the other components that use BASE component, by including it's header, the macro expands as `__declspec(dllimport)` on MSVC and nothing on GCC/Clang. This helps the other components to import stuff from dependent components.

This supports implicit dynamic linking if these modules while load.

While a regular build, this macro expands to nothing.

Refer: 
[Chromium Modularization](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chromium-modularization)
[Component build / Shared Library / Multi-DLL build](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/component-build)
[Exporting Symbols](https://www.chromium.org/developers/coding-style#TOC-Exporting-Symbols)

Also refer, [GCC visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility), [MSVC import/export](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx).